# Extract text from value tag Etree XML python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I want to extract text from a `value` tag, my xml code fragment and tries are as given below:

```
<datas>
  <data>
    <column datatype='string' name='[Sub-Category (group)]' role='dimension' type='nominal'>
      <calculation class='categorical-bin' column='[Product Sub-Category]' new-bin='false'>
        <bin value='&quot;Envelopes&quot;'>
          <value>&quot;Envelopes&quot;</value>
          <value>&quot;Labels&quot;</value>
          <value>&quot;Pens &amp; Art Supplies&quot;</value>
          <value>&quot;Rubber Bands&quot;</value>
          <value>&quot;Scissors, Rulers and Trimmers&quot;</value>
        </bin>
      </calculation>
   </column>      
</data>
</datas>
```

MY try:

```
root = 'myxmlfile.xml'
valuelist = []
for i in root.findall('./datas/data/column/calculation/bin')
    val  = i.find('value')
    if val:
       for j in val:
           valuelist.append(j.text)
```

- I didn't get proper result.

Comment: you are not closing column tag in your xml file also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
root = open('/your/path_to_file/data.xml', 'rb+')
doc =  ET.parse(root).getroot()
valuelist = []
for i in doc.findall('.//bin'):
    val  = i.findall('value')
    for v in val:
        valuelist.append(v.text)
print valuelist
```

Output:

```
['"Envelopes"', '"Labels"', '"Pens & Art Supplies"', '"Rubber Bands"', '"Scissors, Rulers and Trimmers"']
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = """<datas>
  <data>
<column datatype='string' name='[Sub-Category (group)]' role='dimension' type='nominal'>
              <calculation class='categorical-bin' column='[Product Sub-Category]' new-bin='false'>
                <bin value='&quot;Envelopes&quot;'>
                  <value>&quot;Envelopes&quot;</value>
                  <value>&quot;Labels&quot;</value>
                  <value>&quot;Pens &amp; Art Supplies&quot;</value>
                  <value>&quot;Rubber Bands&quot;</value>
                  <value>&quot;Scissors, Rulers and Trimmers&quot;</value>
                </bin>
              </calculation>
    </column>
 </data>
</datas>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree = et.fromstring(s)
for i in tree.findall('.//data/column/calculation/bin'):
    for j in i.findall('value'):
        print(j.text)
```

**Output**:

```
"Envelopes"
"Labels"
"Pens & Art Supplies"
"Rubber Bands"
"Scissors, Rulers and Trimmers"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rakesh's answer is great, just thought I'd add a bit of explanation of why your code wasn't working.

To begin with you need to convert your XML into an ElementTree - this is basically just a Python object with a tree-like structure of elements and subelements that corresponds to your XML, but is something you can then work with in Python.

If your XML is in a file (rather than just a string within your code), you can do:

```
tree = ET.parse('myxmlfile.xml')
```

The `root` is then the "outermost" element of this tree, which you need to get hold of to be able to work your way around the tree and find elements etc:

```
root = tree.getroot()
```

(If you do `ET.fromstring(s)`, this returns the root element so you don't need the getroot step.)

In your example, `root` is the `datas` element, which was one of your problems: your path doesn't need to include 'datas' as that's where you're starting from already.

`val = i.find('value')` will only return the first `value` element, not a list of all the `value` elements which is what you want. So when you try to do `for j in val`, Python is actually trying to find subelements of the `value` element (which don't exist) so it doesn't have anything to append to `valuelist`. You need to use `findall()` here, and if you combine this with a `for` loop, then you don't need to do the `if val` check, as the `for` loop simply won't run if `findall()` comes back empty.

Putting all this together:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('myxmlfile.xml')  # change to wherever your file is located
root = tree.getroot()

binlist = []
for i in root.findall('./data/column/calculation/bin'):
    valuelist = []
    for j in i.findall('value'):
        valuelist.append(j.text)
    binlist.append(valuelist)
```

`binlist` is then a list, with each item in the list being a list of values for that bin.

If you only have one bin, then you can simplify the second half of the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('myxmlfile.xml')  # change to wherever your file is located
root = tree.getroot()

bin = root.find('./data/column/calculation/bin')
valuelist = []
for j in bin.findall('value'):
   valuelist.append(j.text)
```

Note that I've used `ET` not `et` for the import of `ElementTree` (this seems to be the convention). This also assumes that `datas` is the first element of your XML. If the snippet you've given is some nested inside a bigger XML file, you'll need to get to that element first by doing something like:

```
bin = root.find('<path to bin element>')
```

These references might be helpful for you:

- I found this quite helpful as an introduction when I was learning to use ElementTree: http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm
- This is more detailed, and also covers iter() and iterparse(): https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/15/processing-xml-in-python-with-elementtree
- The official docs are quite good too: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html